# How to send single email with more than one lead records with their status

Tags: apex-email-service

I have a requirement which needs to send an single email with more multiple records. I have ABC custom object which have leads and contacts as related list. If a contact field is ticked then an email should be sent to contact about the ABC leads and their status.

ex: contact email Id: abc@test.com & email body should be as below:

Lead name: abc, Status: Open.
Lead name: xyz, Status: qualified.
Lead name: abcTest, Status: closed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give all details in email body. What is issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Tushar and developer__c for the quick reply.
here is my code below:
I am able to send an email to the contact. but need to have multiple leads in the email body.
I am working on it and will update later.

```
Contact c=[select ownerid, id, email from Contact where id=:trigger.newMap.keySet()];
        for (contact co : Trigger.new){
            if(co.TestField__c == true){  
            String userEmail = co.Email; 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {userEmail}; 
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
        mail.setSubject('Automated email: Contact created'); 
            String body = ('body'); 
            mail.setPlainTextBody(body); 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEMailMessage[]{mail});
        } 
    } 
}
```